# Android android.view.windowManagerBadToken exception Only in 10 inch tab?

Tags: android, popup

This happen only 10 inch tab(remaining tabs and  handsets it's working fine),How to solve this issue any one have idea of this.

this is the code im useing.

```
Addr_EditText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {        
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {                    

            LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(mainactivity.getApplicationContext());
            final View DialogView = factory.inflate(R.layout.custom_popup, null);
            final AlertDialog Dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mainactivity.getApplicationContext()).create();
            Dialog.setView(DialogView);

            //Dialog.show();            
            popupEditText =(EditText)DialogView.findViewById(R.id.editText_popup);
            //input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);

            popupEditText.setText(Addr_Title_fromsidepannel.toString());
            popupEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                    if ((event != null && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) || (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)) {
                        Addr_EditText.setText(Addr_EditText.getText());
                        Addr_Popup_title.setText(popupEditText.getText()+ " Configuration");
                        Addr_Title_fromsidepannel.setText(popupEditText.getText());
                        //editor.putString("newname", input.getText().toString());
                        //editor.apply();
                        Dialog.dismiss();
                    }    
                    return false;
                }                                                
            });

            popupEditText.setSelection(popupEditText.getText().length());
            DialogView.findViewById(R.id.okbutton).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Addr_EditText.setText(popupEditText.getText());
                    Addr_Popup_title.setText(popupEditText.getText()+ " Configuration");
                    Addr_Title_fromsidepannel.setText(popupEditText.getText());
                    //editor.putString("newname", input.getText().toString());
                    //editor.apply();
                    Dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            DialogView.findViewById(R.id.cancelbutton).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            Dialog.show();                       
        }
    });
```

Logcat

```
08-21 14:05:47.100: E/SpannableStringBuilder(18756): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
08-21 14:05:47.100: E/SpannableStringBuilder(18756): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
08-21 14:05:47.120: D/AndroidRuntime(18756): Shutting down VM
08-21 14:05:47.120: W/dalvikvm(18756): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4209a300)
08-21 14:05:47.120: E/AndroidRuntime(18756): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-21 14:05:47.120: E/AndroidRuntime(18756): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@428466f0 is not valid; is your activity running? 
08-21 14:05:47.120: E/AndroidRuntime(18756):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:585)
08-21 14:05:47.120: E/AndroidRuntime(18756):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:326) 
08-21 14:05:47.120: E/AndroidRuntime(18756):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
08-21 14:05:47.120: E/AndroidRuntime(18756):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
08-21 14:05:47.120: E/AndroidRuntime(18756):    at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:547)
08-21 14:05:47.120: E/AndroidRuntime(18756):    at android.widget.PopupWindow.invokePopup(PopupWindow.java:988)
08-21 14:05:47.120: E/AndroidRuntime(18756):    at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAtLocation(PopupWindow.java:845)
08-21 14:05:47.120: E/AndroidRuntime(18756):    at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAtLocation(PopupWindow.java:809)
08-21 14:05:47.120: E/AndroidRuntime(18756):    at android.widget.Editor$PinnedPopupWindow.updatePosition(Editor.java:2147)
08-21 14:05:47.120: E/AndroidRuntime(18756):    at android.widget.Editor$PinnedPopupWindow.show(Editor.java:2104)
08-21 14:05:47.120: E/AndroidRuntime(18756):    at android.widget.Editor$SuggestionsPopupWindow.show(Editor.java:2349)
08-21 14:05:47.120: E/AndroidRuntime(18756):    at android.widget.Editor.showSuggestions(Editor.java:1647)
08-21 14:05:47.120: E/AndroidRuntime(18756):    at android.widget.Editor$1.run(Editor.java:1546)
08-21 14:05:47.120: E/AndroidRuntime(18756):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
08-21 14:05:47.120: E/AndroidRuntime(18756):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-21 14:05:47.120: E/AndroidRuntime(18756):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-21 14:05:47.120: E/AndroidRuntime(18756):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
08-21 14:05:47.120: E/AndroidRuntime(18756):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-21 14:05:47.120: E/AndroidRuntime(18756):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-21 14:05:47.120: E/AndroidRuntime(18756):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
08-21 14:05:47.120: E/AndroidRuntime(18756):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-21 14:05:47.120: E/AndroidRuntime(18756):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: The error occurs when your context is invalid mainactivity.getApplicationContext() what does this resolve to. try changing the context to MainActivity.this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you are using `mainactivity.getApplicationContext()` in

`AlertDialog Dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mainactivity.getApplicationContext()).create();`

thats not the way to use it, instead you can simply try using, `v.getContext()`

`AlertDialog Dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext()).create();`

**UPDATE:**

Also, the samething you are doing it here too,

`LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(mainactivity.getApplicationContext());`

you can change that too with `v.getContext()`

`LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(v.getContext());`

**Further Update**

If you are already having `Context` or instance of `Activity` then you can simply use that

`LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(mainactivity);`
`AlertDialog Dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mainactivity).create();`

Comment: still same issue, actually this is not a activity, when i click button one popup is raising in that popup edittext clickable in that time this method is raise.

Comment: If this is not an Activity, then you should pass the `context` of Activity from where it is called in its constructor and use that `context`

Comment: I updated my answer, as you are inflating Layout again with wrong context!

Comment: public Addr1Leftpannel(MainActivity mainactivity) {
  this.mainactivity=mainactivity; 
  context = mainactivity;
   initComponents();      
 }

Comment: trying all the possible ways like(context, mainactivity, ....) but still same issue...

Comment: hope you are not finishing the activity whose, context is being used here!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59711/discussion-between-nagarjunareddy-and-prabuddha).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
final AlertDialog Dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mainactivity.getApplicationContext()).create();
```

Use

```
final AlertDialog Dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
        Dialog.setView(DialogView);
```

Comment: still same issue, actually this is not a activity, when i click button one popup is raising in that popup edittext clickable in that time this method is raise.